# How to convert a whole number(which is minutes) to a time format DD:HH:MM

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

First of all, thank you for reading this question

So, I have a set of data which is the difference between two date in "minutes" the raw data type is "Whole Number"
I would like to convert it to be "DD:HH:MM", not sure if anyone could help me, thank you so much!

[image: the result I want]

[image: that is what I did but cannot show it in Power BI properly]

Comment: Do you really need that *exact* format, or would you rather have a `Duration` type? The latter is easily achieved with `#duration(0, 0, [minutevalue], 0)` (e.g. `Table.TransformColumns(Source,{{"minutes", each #duration(0, 0, _, 0)}})` in a custom transformation step). Formatting it exactly as `DD:HH:MM` is surprisingly much more involved, since durations can't be custom formatted and `Duration.ToRecord` is unhelpful for negative values.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, just need the Duration is fine
and actually, i just update the question, i believe it is showing D.HH:MM:SS in the Query, but just not showing properly in power BI :(

Comment: The duration appears to be formatted in a peculiar way where the day is omitted for negative durations that are smaller than 1 day, whereas 0 is shown for positive durations. This doesn't affect the value, though. Interestingly, this is inconsistent with the result of `Duration.ToText`, which omits the 0 value for days for positive values as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, Power BI does not have or recognize a `duration type`.  If you want to display in that format, it will need to be text.

In Power Query you can transform that column to text with code such as:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45W0jU0NDVUitUBskwtTSAMYwhtCSZNzCAcCzBlZAjhGhqbQATMzC3NlWJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Minutes = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Minutes", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Transform to Duration" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Minutes", each Duration.ToText(#duration(0,0,_,0)), type text})
in
    #"Transform to Duration"
```

Then, in Desktop, format that column as Text

If you need to do calculations on the duration, you may want to add a column instead of transforming the column, or do the calculations in Power Query.

Answer (score 0):

//You can use this

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"duration", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each [duration]/1440),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", type duration}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).